# Open graph meta tags not ok?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have this url:

http://tomatoweb.it/blog/ecommerce-sostenibile

It seems to me all the meta tags for the open graph protocol are ok, but when I try to debug it on Facebook I always get errors. It seems like my metas can't be found.

Can someone help me out please? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check the problem you are facing by debugging at [Open Graph Object Debugger](http://tomatoweb.it/blog/ecommerce-sostenibile).